# formula to match person by start end range in another sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

What formula in excel would take a value and then look into a set of ranges from another sheet to determine which range it falls under, In this example the formula for "Person" column would need to take the "Location" column value and then look into sheet 2 for who handles that location by their start and end range columns. I have googled this but am coming up blank. It needs to be dynamic as the persons start/end ranges change. I'd like to avoid VBA

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8HQ8.png)

i tried to google this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=IFERROR(FILTER($A$2:$A$5,(A10>=$B$2:$B$5)*(A10<=$C$2:$C$5)),"null")
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Lots of typing cf a vlookup.

Comment: @SolarMike while I agree with that, formula is written according to given data sample without making assumptions that it can be easily modified (what if it is automatically populated) and real dataset is that short (what if there are n gaps to fill manually to show "null") :)

Comment: So could you automatically populate it  and still set it up like I did?

Answer (score 0):

So use vlookup() like this:

[image]

```
VLOOKUP(A16,$A$3:$B$12,2,1)
```

Comment: What happens with 3.3?  It should return 'Null'.

Comment: @sous2817 edited and a lot less typing cf the other answer.

Comment: I like it!  poster will have to expand his table a bit, but it makes sense and would be easy to explain to someone.  Nice work!